# Possible approach to secure a Rest API endpoints using Facebook OAuth

Tags: facebook, api, rest, oauth

I've been reading a lot about the topic but all I find are obsolete or partial answers, which don't really help me that much and actually just confused me more.
I'm writing a Rest API (Node+Express+MongoDB) that is accessed by a web app (hosted on the same domain than the API) and an Android app.

I want the API to be accessed only by my applications and only by authorized users.
I also want the users to be able to signup and login only using their Facebook account, and I need to be able to access some basic info like name, profile pic and email.

A possible scenario that I have in mind is:

1. The user logs-in on the web app using Facebook, the app is granted
   permission to access the user Facebook information and receives an
   access token.
2. The web app asks the API to confirm that this user
   is actually registered on our system, sending the email and the
   token received by Facebook.
3. The API verifies that the user
   exists, it stores into the DB (or Redis) the username, the token and
   a timestamp and then goes back to the client app.
4. Each time the
   client app hits one of the API endpoint, it will have to provide the
   username and the token, other than other info.
5. The API each time
   verifies that the provided pair username/token matches the most
   recent pair username/token stored into the DB (using the timestamp
   to order), and that no more than 1 hour has passed since we stored
   these info (again using the timestamp). If that's the case, the API
   will process the request, otherwise will issue a 401 Unauthorized
   response.

Does this make sense? 
Does this approach have any macroscopic security hole that I'm missing?
One problem I see using MongoDB to store these info is that the collection will quickly become bloated with old tokens.
In this sense I think it would be best to use Redis with an expire policy of 1 hour so that old info will be automatically removed by Redis.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think the better solution would be this:

1. Login via Facebook
2. Pass the Facebook AccessToken to the server (over SSL for the
   android app, and for the web app just have it redirect to an API endpoint
   after FB login)
3. Check the `fb_access_token` given, make sure its valid. Get `user_id`,`email` and cross-reference this with existing users to
   see if its a new or old one.
4. Now, create a random, separate `api_access_token` that you give back to the webapp and android app. If you need Facebook for
   anything other than login, store that `fb_access_token` and in your
   DB associate it with the new `api_access_token` and your `user_id`.
5. For every call hereafter, send `api_access_token` to authenticate it. If you need the `fb_access_token` for getting more info, you can
   do so by retrieving it from the DB.

**In summary**: Whenever you can, avoid passing the `fb_access_token`. If the `api_access_token` is compromised, you have more control to see who the attacker is, what they're doing etc than if they were to get ahold of the `fb_access_token`. You also have more control over settings an expiration date, extending `fb_access_token`s, etc

Just make sure whenever you pass a access_token of any sort via HTTP, use SSL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Point 1 and 2 are clear, but how do you exactly check, from the API, that the fb_access_token is valid as per point 3?

Comment: Make a graph call to the `/me` endpoint and check the response.

Comment: Ok I see, so basically calling /me is going to send me back the current access token issued for the user and all I have to do is check if the two tokens match. 
Thank you!

Comment: No. It will return a User object if it is valid, or an error if it is not.

Comment: Ok then I will compare against the email! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, I finally implemented all this and it worked like a charm :D

Comment: And I also wrote a blog post to detail: http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/how-to-secure-your-http-api-endpoints-using-facebook-as-oauth-provider/

Comment: Hi! I think that we can not trust that the User object returned by facebook has always a email. I tested this yesterday and the email was not returned in my case. The facebook sdk says: "The person's primary email address listed on their profile. This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available". I suppose that the only alternative is to use the user_id (this is always returned) to create a user in our backend api. What do you think?

Comment: Great answer @TommyCrush ! I was wanting to just confirm the flow of the `fb_access_token`.  Its ok to have the `fb_access_token` returned from facebook to the android app then sent over the wire where it should be stored in the server side DB where it then returns the  `api_access_token` to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'd like to add a visual representation of this process as I'm dealing with this problem right now (specifically in dealing with the communication between the mobile app and the web api by securing it with a 3rd party provider like facebook).

For simplicity, I haven't included error checks, this is mostly just to outline a reasonable approach. Also for simplicity, I haven't included Tommy's suggestion to only pass your own custom api token once the authorization flow is over, although I agree that this is probably a good approach.

Please feel free to criticize this approach though, and I'll update as necessary.

Also, in this scenario, "My App" refers to a mobile application.

[image]