# Secure rest api with 3rd party login provider

Tags: facebook, web-services, api, security, rest

I've got a web app that currently allows users to login via Facebook. This is the only login mechanism at present. I make use of the user id and the users friends to perform certain actions. Now I want to create an api that I can use to create a native mobile app. To do this, I would need to authenticate users against the api. I've looked at this question

[Possible approach to secure a Rest API endpoints using Facebook OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602667/possible-approach-to-secure-a-rest-api-endpoints-using-facebook-oauth)

but I don't actually have a "user" table as I only pull the facebook info when I need it. In iOS or something similar I could obviously make use of the native facebook sdk and then call my api, passing in the required user id and friend ids etc. however I'm not sure then how I could specifically secure my api so that if a user got hold of another's user_id they could in theory retrieve info via the api or in theory any resource that only specific users should be able to see

I thought about creating an app_id and app_secret for all the separate apps consuming the api. I would then use the appropriate secret to encrypt the data being sent and returned. The api and native app would know the secret and be able to decrypt it and validate that a user can view the requested resource. Does this sounds like a valid approach? In theory only the native apps would then be able to decrypt what is returned from the api. Or should this really be done on a user by user basis as recommended in the linked post?

All of this would be done over https

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with the Facebook API nor iOS so I am speaking completely in theoretical terms.

Could you not:

1. Ask the user to login with Facebook on the iOS app
2. Send the login data over a secure channel to your web application to handle the actual processing of the data
3. Send the iOS app a secure hash for authentication
4. Use your web application as needed; using the hash for authentication, make HTTPS requests as you would your web application and use the responses from the webserver to populate the iOS app

If you make a `user_hash` column a complex salted hash like a SHA-256 (or greater) hash, the user_hash will become invalid before anybody is able to guess the hash. You could save the user's Facebook credentials locally on the iOS device and then renew the hash every so often, as to invalidate old hashes and lock out perpetrators (like how a cookie expires). If the user hash somehow becomes invalidated while using the iOS app, the app will send the locally stored credentials and retrieve a new one.

If Apple offers cookies for apps, you could send the hash in a cookie from your webpage and give it a reasonable expiry time (e.g. 1 day). You'd be resending the locally stored Facebook credentials every day and be effectively locking out anybody trying to bruteforce your hashes. Use that instead of trying to implement cookies from scratch (if the iOS API offers that), but as I said, I'm unfamiliar with iOS.

From an SQL standpoint, your webpage would validate a user's Facebook credentials, create a new row with a randomly generated `user_hash`, `expires` timestamp, `user_id`, `friends_id`, etc. Every user that uses the webpage will have to send the `user_hash` either from their web-client or the iOS app and will be checked against the database. If the present timestamp exceeds the `expires` timestamp, the session is ruled invalid and the user cannot operate your application.

Of course, you'd need to encrypt the communication. Do you pass credentials everytime the user loads a page on your web app? Or do you store them in a session?

Hope this helps at least somewhat!

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. The facebook token is stored as a session and there is a facebook endpoint I can validate that against. But a number of posts advice against passing that token back and forth hence my dilemma

Comment: @TommyBs Don't pass the facebook token around, assign a `user_hash` in for every row that holds the facebook token. That way you can get it only when you need it.

Comment: I wouldn't keep passing it around, but it would need to be validated at least once by my api to ensure that the user who has requested my own user_hash variable is indeed who they say they are